# Plot standardized sizes with or without legends (ggplot, grid.arrange)

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid-layout

I have a serie of plots (more than 10) arranged on 2 colonnes using grid.arrange. Since they all possess the same x axis labels, I am ploting the x axis labels only for the last array. However, the plots part of the last array are compressed and reduced in size

Here is a reproducible example of the problem:

```
source("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/arbuthnot.R")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)

names(arbuthnot) <- c("Year", "Men", "Women")

arbuthnot.melt <- melt(arbuthnot, id.vars = 'Year', variable.name = 'Sex', 
                       value.name = 'Rate')

p1 <- ggplot(arbuthnot.melt, aes(x = Year, y = Rate, shape = Sex, color = Sex, linetype = Sex))+
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("Women" = '#ff00ff','Men' = '#3399ff')) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('Women' = 'solid', 'Men' = 'dotted')) +
  theme (axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(arbuthnot.melt, aes(x = Year, y = Rate, shape = Sex, color = Sex, linetype = Sex))+
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("Women" = '#ff00ff','Men' = '#3399ff')) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('Women' = 'solid', 'Men' = 'dotted')) +
  theme (axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())

p3 <- ggplot(arbuthnot.melt, aes(x = Year, y = Rate, shape = Sex, color = Sex, linetype = Sex))+
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("Women" = '#ff00ff','Men' = '#3399ff')) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('Women' = 'solid', 'Men' = 'dotted')) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), labels=c("FSSFDFSDSDF", "ASD","QDDZXCC","QDDZXCC","QDDZXCC")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle=90))

p4 <- ggplot(arbuthnot.melt, aes(x = Year, y = Rate, shape = Sex, color = Sex, linetype = Sex))+
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("Women" = '#ff00ff','Men' = '#3399ff')) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('Women' = 'solid', 'Men' = 'dotted')) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), labels=c("FSSFDFSDSDF", "ASD","QDDZXCC","QDDZXCC","QDDZXCC")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle=90))

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Is it possible to standardize the plot formats with no regards to the fact that they possess or not a legend? Im my case, it is even impossible to read the content of the last two plots...

Comment: The cowplot package has plot_grid which features lots of options like this

Comment: can you use `facet-wrap`?